# How to get mysql data variable value outside in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

In the code below, `expRow`, `lanRow` and `skillRow` variables end up `undefined`. How can I get those values from queries? I don't want to use mysql joint like left, right or inner join. I am using multiple query section and get all function values in those 3 variables.

```
var lan_Execute_innerQuery = "SELECT * FROM language LEFT JOIN languagedata ON language.l_id = languagedata.inner_join WHERE language.l_id = ?";
var exp_Execute_innerQuery = "SELECT * FROM experience LEFT JOIN experiencedata ON experience.exp_id = experiencedata.inner_join WHERE experience.exp_id = ?";
var skill_Execute_innerQuery = "SELECT * FROM skilltable LEFT JOIN skilldata ON skilltable.s_id = skilldata.inner_join WHERE skilltable.s_id = ?";
            connection.query(skill_Execute_innerQuery,rows[0].s_id,function(err,skillRow,field){
    if(err) throw err;
});
            connection.query(exp_Execute_innerQuery,rows[0].exp_id,function(err,expRow,field){
    if(err) throw err;
});
            connection.query(lan_Execute_innerQuery,rows[0].l_id,function(err,lanRow,field){
    if(err) throw err;
});
var html = view.compileFile('templates/profile.html')({
    title:"Profile",
    exitUser : true,
    data : rows,
    skillData : skillRow,
    expData : expRow,
    lanData : lanRow
});
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
res.end(html);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "html function"?

Comment: Sorry not html function , html variable ..

Comment: In html variable skillRow , lanRow and expRow values are undefined and these values are show into connection query . I want to these value also show into HTML variable...

Comment: Do you have any successful queries? (are your sure that table names and other stuff is correct and the tables are not empty? are there any error messages?)

Comment: Tables name are correct and if II placed html variable into connection query values are show but outside connection query values are not coming.